Group of problematic teenagers gathered in reality show to earn $1 mil?
Problematic teenagers are gathered on a reality show, most of em were involved in sexual-related cases, for example one girl was raped by the brother for a year before she killed her brother in self defense. 
So they are asked to "survive" in this show until only one person remains, the method of dying was mentioned to be hit by paint ball, tapped on the shoulder and such. However real killings were happening, I only saw a guy got shot by an arrow through his eyes.
I believe this movie is quite new but have no further information on what it could be, any ideas?

This is very recent indeed: It's Camp Dread (AKA Dead.tv) from 2014. From an online synopsis:

In the 1980s, Julian Barrett (Eric Roberts) was the filmmaker behind the successful Summer Camp trilogy of slasher films. [...] Enlisting his two former embattled Summer Camp stars, John (Brian Gallagher) and Rachel (Felissa Rose), for the endeavor, Barrett tricks a group of troubled teens into thinking they’re going to be attending a rehab outward bound camp. When they arrive, he informs them of their true roles. Instead of rehab, or jail, they are to be contestants on a reality show based loosely on the Summer Camp franchise. A “killer” is loose at the camp, and the contestants have to go about getting the camp ready for opening while avoiding being, say, stabbed with a fake machete or shot with a paintball gun. The one who can survive until the very end will win one million dollars.

One of the contestants was raped by her brother until she killed him. Here's the trailer (slightly NSFW):



